# connecting java to microsoft dynamics crm

Tags: java, microsoft-dynamics, adal

I´ve been investigating about the best way to connecting java to ms dynamics crm and what i read is all about crm dynamics 2011 version with the 2011 sdk java samples but i have a lot of problems authenticating and inserting data into CRM databases. i can´t find any information about java and the web api for CRM 2016 and tutorials, my questions are:

1- What is the best (and updated) way to connect Java with CRM 2016?

2- Is there any tutorial for that purpose?

3- It´s possible to retrieve,insert,delete, update... in dynamics crm with java in 2016 crm version?

All the help is welcome,I´m a little bit lost, thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to make your Java application access the CRM web services/api, check this page on MSDN to download the WSDL [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309401.aspx) to be able to perform CRUD operations.

There is this old (2011) example for java [MSDN CRM 2011 Java example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979(v=crm.5).aspx)